# $a,b,c>0: a^2+b^2+c^2=3$, prove: $\frac{\sqrt{a+b}}{a+b+\sqrt{c}}+\frac{\sqrt{b+c}}{b+c+\sqrt{a}}+\frac{\sqrt{c+a}}{c+a+\sqrt{b}}\ge \sqrt{2}$

Tags: inequality

> **Problem.** Let $a,b,c>0: a^2+b^2+c^2=3$. Prove that:
> $$\frac{\sqrt{a+b}}{a+b+\sqrt{c}}+\frac{\sqrt{b+c}}{b+c+\sqrt{a}}+\frac{\sqrt{c+a}}{c+a+\sqrt{b}}\ge \sqrt{2}$$ I saw it in math group Facebook. All I can say about it is that extremely tight and hard.

Here is my attempt:

I used AM-GM: $$\frac{\sqrt{a+b}}{\dfrac{a+b}{\sqrt[4]{\dfrac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{3}}}+\sqrt{c}}\ge \frac{\sqrt{a+b}}{\dfrac{a+b}{\sqrt{\dfrac{a+b+c}{3}}}+\sqrt{c}}$$
But it is not true. I wonder how to use the given condition $a^2+b^2+c^2=3$.

The following idea is also wrong already: $a=b\rightarrow 0$: $$3\sqrt[3]{\frac{\sqrt{a+b}}{a+b+\sqrt{c}}.\frac{\sqrt{b+c}}{b+c+\sqrt{a}}.\frac{\sqrt{c+a}}{c+a+\sqrt{b}}}\ge \sqrt{2}$$
Finally, I cam up with C-S's idea which means we need to prove: $$\left(\sqrt{a+b}+\sqrt{b+c}+\sqrt{c+a}\right)^2\ge \sqrt{2}\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{a+b}\left(a+b+\sqrt{c}\right)$$
It seems complicated to me. Could you please give me hint to continue my C-S idea ? Is there a better approach to deal with given condition?

Thank you!

Comment: $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt{a+b}}{a+b+\sqrt[3]c}\geq\sqrt2$ with the same condition is also true, but it's  a bit of greater sadism. An inequality with $\sqrt[4]c$ is wrong already.

Comment: Yeah, it is so hard to me. Have you checked my C'S idea ?

Comment: I checked. It seems true, but I don't know to prove it.

Comment: Dear @MichaelRozenberg, is there a solution for starting inequality even it is ugly ?

Comment: I have no a solution.

Comment: Until now, it is unsolved. Very hard problem.